# Portainer business edition fails to load container list with error

Tags: ubuntu, docker, portainer

Error message is:

> 2023/04/25 10:13AM ERR
> github.com/portainer/portainer-ee/api/docker/images/status.go:204 >
> error when fetch remote digest for image |
> image=docker.io/vaultwarden/server:latest

Container list hangs never ending.

VM is behind a firewall and I guess the check for a new image is hanging.
Docker run hello-world for example is running without problems, also from Portainer itself.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Portainer business edition 2.17.1 licensed,
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 on VMWare

Comment: New Portainer Business Edition Version: 2.18.1 does not solve this problem

Comment: Divide and conquer: check if problem is indeed FW related (by temporarily disabling it fot this host, for example), then if so, find rule that is causing problem. And than consider creating exception in this rule. And if it is not feasible explain why, what exact rule is causing problem, and your expectations on matter.

Answer (score 0):

I now use this docker run and have no more problems:

```
docker run -d -p 8001:8000 -p 9445:9443 -e HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy:myproxy-port -e HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy:myproxy-port --name=portainer --restart=always --pull=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ee:latest
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by starting the container with `--network=host`